# Polygon stops when the mirror modifier is turned on and carved in Sculpt mode

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

[image]

I want to carve with the mirror Modifier on. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use mirror modifier for sculpting? Sculpt mode allows for symmetry already.

Comment: I want to model while maintaining the square. That's why I'm going to write it.